# Ubuntu apache error server reached MaxRequestWorkers on increase to 1024

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server

Need help for my apache errors,

I am getting these errors from error log file

```
[Thu Jul 27 12:16:05.788246 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18180] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 27 12:19:54.149332 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 19376] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

My settings(mpm_prefork.conf) :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers                     5
    MinSpareServers           5
    MaxSpareServers          10
    MaxRequestWorkers         1024
    ServerLimit               256
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Increasing MaxRequestWorkers not solving this issue, kindly help where i am going wrong.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related *infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: thanks for advice, its basically apache configuration, and itself more question similar to this posted here than server. but not to far, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who found out this question, the `MaxRequestWorkers` value should be `equal` or `less` than to the value of `ServerLimit`.